# django-admin makemessages => translate all django package with mine

Tags: python, django

i am currently trying to start translation on a website.
the isue is that django makemessages utilitie nicely generate le PO file but he include ALL the django package to translate. with 10 sentance in my website, i have 5370 lines in my po file.

i am working with virtualenv,django 1.3, python 2.6

trace of my actions :

```
mkdir locale
django-admin.py makemessages -l en
```

the po file start with

```
  20 #: env_website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django  /conf/global_settings.py:44
  21 msgid "Arabic"
  22 msgstr ""
```

my question is : what have i done wrong and how to exclude the django package ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

makemessages should be run from either the project root or application root. It will walk through the source tree to find strings marked for translation. If you have directories you want to avoid use the --ignore option.

Example from the docs:

```
django-admin.py makemessages --locale=en_US --ignore=apps/* --ignore=secret/*.html
```

Comment: after a check, the django package was translated because my virtualenv dir was in the root directory.